# Repository EF CF Fails referencing to non existing field

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I am building the Data Access Layer using Repository pattern and Code First for .NET Core. I had no problem with Code First when it was just the regular .NET Framework, but I have lots of the issues with the .NET Core.

The current one is: I have the bunch of simple classes and I am trying to get just the list of the what's stored in the table and I get a strange error message:
Invalid column name 'AspNetUserId'. However I don't have such the column name. I have a table AspNetUsers and it has a field Id. The other tables which are referenced with this table use UserId field as a FK.

Below is the simplified code of the major classes:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
...
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH ...


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Accounts](
    [AccountAddress] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
...
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Accounts_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AccountAddress] ASC
)WITH...


    public class AspNetUser
    {
        [Key]        
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; } // Id (Primary key)

      ...
  }

 public class DataContext : DbContext   
 {
        public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }

        public DbSet<AspNetUser> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
        ...

 }

 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
            modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUser>()
                .HasMany(p => p.Accounts)
                .WithOne(p => p.AspNetUser);

            modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUser>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Currency);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Currency);

          ...


            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
 }
```

Comment: I changed the property name AspNetUser of the Account class to       public virtual AspNetUser User { get; set; }  and it resolved the issue. I don't know why it was a problem...

Comment: Because the navigation property name controls the *default* FK property name (hence the default FK column name). For `User` it's `UserId`, for `AspNetUser` it's `AspNetUserId` etc.

Comment: @JackSmith Add your `AspNetUsers` model class and its associate model classes also to the question please!